# IEEE-754 single precision floating point mips

Tags: precision, floating-point-precision

How I write -2^-132 in hexadecimal format in IEEE-754 single precision?

Answer (score 1):

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for how to represent it in IEEE-754.

Or even [this link](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html).

Note: the result is [denormal](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), so the exponent is zero!

According to [this](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=80020000) and [this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=-2%5E-132), the answer is:

0x80020000 == 10000000000000100000000000000000b

Comment: Hi @anilcheetri, was my answer what you were looking for? If so, would you mind marking it as an answer please? It'll [boost](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your reputation (as well as mine) and persuade others to answer your questions in future if you accept answers to questions you've asked in the past. Many thanks, Wai Ha.

Comment: ... If it's not what you wanted, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me *why* so that I could improve any answers I give in future.